# Arranging 4 identical items in 7 spots

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

There are 4 unique items, for the sake of the example call them balls. Each ball is exactly the same, and we need to see how many different ways those 4 balls can fit in those 7 slots.

I am not sure what the process is for similar problems as well. How would I do this with 5 balls and 12 slots? Or 3 balls and 8 slots?

Comment: Is this a Mathematica question?

Comment: This is a math question, perhaps you intended to ask at [`Mathematics StackExchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The number  of ways to choose 4 places out of 7 is given by Binomial[7,4]

Comment: In textbook form: `RowBox[{
   Defer@TraditionalForm[Binomial[7, 4]]
   , "="
   , Binomial[7, 4]
   }] // DisplayForm`